# PHP Syntax Error Registration System

Tags: php, syntax

I am not that good at PHP, so can you please tell me what is wrong here?

What happens is that I get a syntax error an it drives me crazy. I try to run the script, but it only gives me a syntax error. I have tried everything I know of, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\als\register.php on line 15

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if ( $_POST['register']) {
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if($getuser) {
        if($getemail) {
            if($getpass){
                if($getretypepass) {
                    if( $getpass === $getretypepass ) {
                        if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 6 ) && (strstr($getmeial, "@")) && (strstr($getmeial, ".")){
                            require("./config.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM strizon WHERE user='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0) {
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM strizon WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                if ($numrows == 0) {

                                    $pass = md5(md5("Jmsad31".$pass."JU821Dkmal"));
                                    $date = date("F d, Y");
                                    $code = md5(rand());

                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO strizon VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$getpass', '$getemail, '0', '$code', '$date')");


                                    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM strizon WHERE user='$getuser'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if($numrows == 1) { 
                                        $site = "http://localhost/als";
                                        $webmaster = "Strizon Account Activiation <noreply@strizon.com>";
                                        $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                        $subject = "Activate your Strizon Account";
                                        $message = "Thank you so much for registering with Strizon. Please click the link below to activate your account.\n";
                                        $message .= "$site/activeate?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                        $message .= "Again, thank you!\n";
                                        $message .= "Sincerely\n";
                                        $message .= "The Strizon Team";

                                        if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                            echo("You have not successfully been registered! You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b>");
                                            $getuser = "";
                                            $getemail = "";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo("An error has occured. Your activation email could not be sent!");

                                        }

                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo("An error has occured, and your account was not created.");

                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo("There is already a user with that email address. Please choose another email address!");
                                }


                            }
                            else {
                                echo("There is already a user with that username. Please choose another username!");
                            }


                            mysql_close();
                        }
                        else {
                            echo("You must enter an valid email address to register!");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo ("Your passwords did not match!");

                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo("You must retype your password to register!")

                }

            }
            else {
                echo("You must enter a password to register!");

            }

        }
        else {
            echo ("You must enter an email address to register!");

        }
    }
<pre>
else {
    echo "You must enter a username to register.";

}
</pre>
    $form = "<form action='' method='post'>
    <br>
    <input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' placeholder='Username'>
    <br>
    <input type='email' name='email' value='$getemail' placeholder='Email Address'>
    <br>
    <input type='password' name='pass' placeholder='Password'>
    <br>
    <input type='password' name='retypepass' placeholder='Retype Password'>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
    ";
    echo($form);

?>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Tapos: read carefully :)

Comment: Hi user3512131. If you install an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse, it will reveal this sort of problem without even needing to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this a messy coding style.

Following mistakes you have:

1)you have missed closing `(` in this line :

```
if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 6 ) && (strstr($getmeial, "@")) && (strstr($getmeial, ".")){
```

2) you have missed `;` in this line:

```
echo("You must retype your password to register!")
```

3) you also missed closing `}` of first if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You had to close the `if-statement` in this line:

```
if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 6 ) && (strstr($getmeial, "@")) && (strstr($getmeial, ".")){
```

Working code:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if ( $_POST['register']) {
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if($getuser) {
        if($getemail) {
            if($getpass){
                if($getretypepass) {
                    if( $getpass === $getretypepass ) {
                        if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 6 ) && (strstr($getmeial, "@")) && (strstr($getmeial, "."))){
                            require("./config.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM strizon WHERE user='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0) {
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM strizon WHERE email='$getemail'");
                                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                if ($numrows == 0) {

                                    $pass = md5(md5("Jmsad31".$pass."JU821Dkmal"));
                                    $date = date("F d, Y");
                                    $code = md5(rand());

                                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO strizon VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$getpass', '$getemail, '0', '$code', '$date')");


                                    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM strizon WHERE user='$getuser'");
                                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                    if($numrows == 1) { 
                                        $site = "http://localhost/als";
                                        $webmaster = "Strizon Account Activiation <noreply@strizon.com>";
                                        $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                        $subject = "Activate your Strizon Account";
                                        $message = "Thank you so much for registering with Strizon. Please click the link below to activate your account.\n";
                                        $message .= "$site/activeate?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
                                        $message .= "Again, thank you!\n";
                                        $message .= "Sincerely\n";
                                        $message .= "The Strizon Team";

                                        if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                            echo("You have not successfully been registered! You must activate your account from the activation link sent to <b>$getemail</b>");
                                            $getuser = "";
                                            $getemail = "";
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            echo("An error has occured. Your activation email could not be sent!");

                                        }

                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo("An error has occured, and your account was not created.");

                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo("There is already a user with that email address. Please choose another email address!");
                                }


                            }
                            else {
                                echo("There is already a user with that username. Please choose another username!");
                            }


                            mysql_close();
                        }
                        else {
                            echo("You must enter an valid email address to register!");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo ("Your passwords did not match!");

                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo("You must retype your password to register!")

                }

            }
            else {
                echo("You must enter a password to register!");

            }

        }
        else {
            echo ("You must enter an email address to register!");

        }
    }
<pre>
else {
    echo "You must enter a username to register.";

}
</pre>
    $form = "<form action='' method='post'>
    <br>
    <input type='text' name='user' value='$getuser' placeholder='Username'>
    <br>
    <input type='email' name='email' value='$getemail' placeholder='Email Address'>
    <br>
    <input type='password' name='pass' placeholder='Password'>
    <br>
    <input type='password' name='retypepass' placeholder='Retype Password'>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
    ";
    echo($form);

?>
```